# Sending data from mysql via php to arduino

Tags: php, json, sqlite, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm trying to receive data from the MySQL server hosted on AwardSpace to my Arduino MEGA2560 using the SIM7600CE, but I'm not receiving any response.
The SQL code attempted to extract the data and transform it into JSON format. When that didn't work, I tried adding a JSON file and using the ArduinoJson library.

Code MySQL

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new PDO('sqlite:readingsDB.sqlite');

// Vérifier la connexion
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed");
}

// Requête SQL pour récupérer les données
$sql = "SELECT humidity FROM reading ORDER BY distance DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result) {
    // Tableau pour stocker les données
    $data = array();

    // Récupérer chaque ligne de résultat
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // Ajouter les données à $data
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    // Convertir le tableau en format JSON
    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    // Renvoyer les données au format JSON
    echo $json_data;
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

I have added a new file named "test.json" for testing purposes.

```
JsonDocument doc;

doc["sensor"] = "gps";
doc["time"] = 1351824120;
doc["data"][0] = 48.756080;
doc["data"][1] = 2.302038;

serializeJson(doc, Serial);
// This prints:
// {"sensor":"gps","time":1351824120,"data":[48.756080,2.302038]}
```

The following code is Arduino code. In this code, I managed to unlock the SIM card SIM7600CE and send SMS messages and data to the server, but I am unable to retrieve data from the server.
Code Arduino

```
/*Ce code utilise la bibliothèque TinyGSM: https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM 
 * pour le module GSM SIM7600
 * Code version 0.3 GSM
*/


#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7600//SIM7600 pour la library GSM fonction network

// Define how you're planning to connect to the internet.
// This is only needed for this example, not in other code.
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI false
#define TINY_GSM_YIELD() { delay(2); }//reception delay

#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 650//obligatoir pour les cartes Arduino

// Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial

// Set serial for AT commands (to the module)
// Use Hardware Serial on Mega, Leonardo, Micro
#ifndef __AVR_ATmega328P__
#define SerialAT Serial3

// or Software Serial on Uno, Nano
#else
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SerialAT(7,8);  // RX, TX
#endif

#include "timer.h" //rajouter le fichier source timer.cpp pour l'utilisation des timers
#include "temperature.h"
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon//pour debuger
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <SPI.h>

TinyGsm SIM7600CE(SerialAT);
TinyGsmClient client(SIM7600CE);

const char apn[]  = "F Free Free "; // Change this to your Provider details
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";
const char server[] = "sms-ileo.atwebpages.com"; // Change this to your selection
const char resource[] = "/insert.php";
const char path[] = "/test.json"; // Chemin vers le script PHP
const int  port = 80;
unsigned long timeout;



void setup() {
  timerConfig();//pré-config des timers
  temperatureInit();
  SerialMon.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  //Debut du boot auto
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(12,1);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(12,0);
  //fin du boot auto
  SerialMon.println("Wait...");
  SerialAT.begin(115200);//met la com UART 115200 pour le module GSM
  //rajouter une fonction de reboot en cas de non reponse de la part du shield GSM
  delay(600);
  SerialMon.println("Initializing SIM7600CE...");

  // Déverrouillage de la carte SIM avec le code PIN
  SerialMon.println("Unlocking SIM card...");
  if (!unlockSIMCard("1234")) { // code PIN
    SerialMon.println("Failed to unlock SIM card!");
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println("SIM card unlocked successfully!");
}




//routine ISR pour interruption externe

//routine ISR pour interruption timer
ISR (TIMER4_OVF_vect)
{ 
   nbCycleTimer4_g=nbCycleTimer4_g+1; 
   
    if(nbCycleTimer4_g < (nbCyclePgrm_g+1))
    {
          if(nbCycleTimer4_g == nbCyclePgrm_g )//test passage de 15 à 20
          {
            SerialMon.println("Objectif timer 4 (PGRM) atteint! ");          
            timerPgrm_g=1;   
            nbCycleTimer4_g=0;//raz
          } 
    }
    else nbCycleTimer4_g=0;//raz
  
  TCNT4H=0x00;
  TCNT4L=0x00;
}

ISR (TIMER3_OVF_vect)
{
  nbCycleTimer3_g=nbCycleTimer3_g+1; 
  
    if(nbCycleTimer3_g < (nbCycleGsm_g+1))
    {
          if(nbCycleTimer3_g == nbCycleGsm_g )//test passage de 15 à 20
          {
            sei();        
            SerialMon.println("Objectif timer 3 (GSM) atteint! ");   
            sendDataTempServeur();
            getdatafromserver();
           

            cli();        
            timerGsm_g=1;   
            nbCycleTimer3_g=0;//raz
            
          } 
    }
    else nbCycleTimer3_g=0;//raz
    
  TCNT3H=0x00;
  TCNT3L=0x00; //reset à chaque passage pour l'overflow     
    
}

void loop() {

  //timerGsm_go(60); //cycle total 60 secondes
  //timerPgrm_go(60); //cycle total 60 secondes
  
  SIM7600CE.init();//si beug remplacer par restart
  SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");

  String modemInfo = SIM7600CE.getModemInfo();
  SerialMon.print("Modem Info: ");
  SerialMon.println(modemInfo);//information du module
  
  if (!SIM7600CE.waitForNetwork()) {
    SerialMon.println(" erreur: La connexion n'a pas pu être établie!");
    // SIM7600CE.sendSMS(SMS_TARGET, String("ILEO erreur: La connexion au réseau mobile n'a pas pu être établie!!"));//fonction pour l'envoi de SMS
    delay(600);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
  
  if (SIM7600CE.isNetworkConnected()) {SerialMon.println("Network connected!");}

  SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
  SerialMon.print(apn);
  if (!SIM7600CE.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (SIM7600CE.isGprsConnected()) {
    SerialMon.println("GPRS connected");
  }
  

  timerGsm_go(30); //cycle total 30 secondes envoi des data sur serveur

  while(1)//program principal 
  {

  }
         
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------- Fonction de Récupération des données -----------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void getdatafromserver(void){

  // Send HTTP request
   client.print("GET ");
    client.print(path);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.0");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println(server);
    client.println(F("Connection: close"));
  if (client.println() == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to send request GET"));
    client.stop();
    return;
  }

  // Check HTTP status
  char status[32] = {0};
  client.readBytesUntil('\r', status, sizeof(status));
  // It should be "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" or "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  if (strcmp(status + 9, "200 OK") != 0) {
    Serial.print(F("Unexpected response: "));
    Serial.println(status);
    client.stop();
    return;
  }

  // Skip HTTP headers
  char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
  if (!client.find(endOfHeaders)) {
    Serial.println(F("Invalid response"));
    client.stop();
    return;
  }

  // Allocate the JSON document
  JsonDocument doc;

  // Parse JSON object
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, client);
  if (error) {
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
    Serial.println(error.f_str());
    client.stop();
    return;
  }

  // Extract values
  Serial.println(F("Response:"));
  Serial.println(doc["sensor"].as<const char*>());
  Serial.println(doc["time"].as<long>());
  Serial.println(doc["data"][0].as<float>(), 6);
  Serial.println(doc["data"][1].as<float>(), 6);

  // Disconnect
  client.stop();
}
```

Comment: "When that didn't work, I tried adding a JSON file" - than did THAT work? Did your Arduino read that file?

Comment: `I'm not receiving any response`...so you don't even see `Unexpected response:...` or `Failed to send request GET` in any output? Or anything else? You were extremely vague about what the code is actually doing, and I didn't get the sense that any meaningful attempt to debug it had taken place. See also [ask] - we can't run your code, so if you want us to diagnose issues with it you'll need to explain exactly what's happening when you run it. Simply staring at the code is usually not sufficient to be able to understand what's wrong - especially when it involved network requests and so on.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, i can see Failed to send request GET, i mean i can't send request GET

Comment: Ok. 1) I don't see anywhere in the code where you've actually specified a URL to send the request to (e.g. `http://example.com/... etc`) - your `path` variable is only `/test.json`, which is just the end of the URL, without the rest of it. 2) Is there a specific reason you're using (ancient) HTTP 1.0 rather than 1.1? There's just a chance the remote server wouldn't like that, if the request ever reaches it. 3) Since you're using TinyGSM, did you check at https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM?tab=readme-ov-file#features that your modem definitely is supported for HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: Your "test.json" is not a valid json file, a valid serialised json object should be `{"sensor":"gps","time":1351824120,"data":[48.756080,2.302038]}`, and your server need to set the correct HTTP header "Content-Type: application/json" as well.

Comment: When you develop a client/server application, it is important to test the server to make sure it is working before you try to write your client code. You can test your server either with app like [PostMan](https://www.postman.com) or linux `curl` command (try `curl sms-ileo.atwebpages.com/test.json -v` to see what your server response). You can also test your client/Arduino code without your own server by using a test server such as http://httpbin.org/ (or https://httpbin.org).

Comment: @hcheung while the OP has named their file "test.json" I think it's actually a piece of code which _outputs_ some JSON. So someone running/requesting that file would see the output, which is JSON. So i don't think that's an issue. But it doesn't seem to be written in PHP so it's unclear how the OP is integrating that into their system for testing. And I very much agree the server-side code needs to be tested and verified correctly before attempting the write the client code, and that doesn't seem to have been done in this case.

Comment: @ADyson, run `curl sms-ileo.atwebpages.com/test.json -v` to see yourself.

Comment: @hcheung evidently then the OP didn't implement it correctly! It's clearly supposed to be a runnable script but they haven't configured it like that. If they're putting it on the server, as it appears, then it would make more sense for it to be PHP - or as you say for it to just contain the static JSON directly.